# Output plot inline in R markdown AND create pdf-file

Tags: rstudio

I have been trying to get the output of RStudio to create the output for a plot inline, in a R markdown script as well as well as create a PDF-document for the image. I use this code:

```
pdf("new_testing.pdf")

test<- ggplot(df, aes(x=curiosity))+
  geom_histogram(fill="blue")

dev.off()

test
```

I manage to create the inline plot if I remove the dev.off()-line, and I manage to create the pdf-plot if I omit having the plot appear inline by removing the test-line after dev.off(). Making both of those outputs happen, have proven to be somehow difficult. They seem to cancle each other out.

Does anyone have any suggestions for how to fix it?

Thanks:)

I have tried to fix it by removing dev.off(), and by moving "test" around in the code.

Comment: Hi Per Flatebø! Welcome to StackOverflow. Thank you for your question. I'm unable to reproduce the problem with the information you have provided. Can you provide more detailed instructions for what you did? Because (for example) I don't see from the code you adding the plot to the PDF